# Scrape multiple individual tables on one web page

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a bunch of tables from one web page, with the code below I can get one table and the output to show correctly with pandas, but I cannot get more than one table at a time.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.URLHERE.com').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.select('table')[-1]
rows = tables.find_all('tr')
output = []

for rows in rows:
    cols = rows.find_all('td') 
    cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols] 
    output.append([item for item in cols if item])
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
df = df.iloc[1:]

print(df)
```

If I remove the [-1] from my table variable then I get the error below.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

What do I need to change to get all the tables off the page?

Comment: Maybe something like that to get all tables: `tables = soup.find_all('table')`?

Comment: I have tried that then I get a different error,
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I am new to web scraping and pretty green with python as well so that is also contributing to my struggles

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track already, just like a commenter already said, you'll need to `find_all` tables, then you can apply the row logic you are already using to each table in a loop instead of just the first table. Your code will look something like this:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for table in tables:
    # individual table logic here

    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        # individual row logic here
```

Comment: I tried including  this into my code, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly, so what I want  to do is scan each table on the page an find all the rows, then take all the table data from those rows and combine them into on big table for my output.

Answer (score 0):

I took a better look on that, and here is the sample code that i tested:

```py
source = urllib.request.urlopen('URL').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
tables = soup.select('table')
print("I found " + str(len(tables)) + " tables.")

all_rows = []
for table in tables:
    print("Searching for <tr> items...")
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    print("Found " + str(len(rows)) + "rows.")
    for row in rows:
        all_rows.append(row)


print("In total i have got " + str(len(all_rows)) + " rows.")

# example of first row
print(all_rows[0])
```

Little explanation: The problem with the Atribute Error when you removed [-1] was, that the `tables` variable was List object - and it don't have `find_all` method.

Your track with [-1] is okay - I assume that you know, that [-1] grabs the last items from list. So the same you have to do with all elements - which is shown in the code above.

You might find interesting to read about `for` construction on python and iterables: https://pythonfordatascience.org/for-loops-and-iterations-python/

Comment: With your example I am able to tell how many rows that I have but what I want to do is extract the data from each cell in those rows and put them in my combine those into my own table. When I combine my changes with my existing code I get another "find_all" error.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: tables = soup.select('table')
all_rows = []
for tables in tables:
    rows = tables.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        all_rows.append(row)
        for data in all_rows:
            cols = all_rows.find_all('td') 
            cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols] 
            output = cols
            output([item for item in cols if item])
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['Teams','Odds', '1', '2', 'T', 'ATS'])
df = df.iloc[1:]
print(df)
Running this produces this
cols = all_rows.find_all('td')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Well, with these changes, you achieve almost all what you ask for. Variable `all_rows` is a list of all rows, in tables at scrapped page; variable `tables` is list of all tables at this page - what you do with that next is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to extract all different tables present on a web-page in one time, you should try :

```
tables = pd.read_html("<URL_HERE>")
```

**tables** would be a list of dataframes for each table present on that page.

For more specific documentation refer to [Pandas-Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)